# Facebook integration in iphone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.3

Sorry for asking the same question which is in stackove flow already . I am trying to integrating Facebook in my iPhone app. To do this i have followed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#sdk . Whenever i am clicking Facebook button in my app it is showing login screen properly. But whenever i click on login button getting an alert as "Safari can not open the page because address is invalid". Read so many questions on stack over flow which are related to my issue but problem not fixed. Even though i have added SSO properly . Ur help is so much appreciated

my info plist is also correct i think.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb432606956784814</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>VJILConsultingLtd.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainWindow</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Still i am not getting it. i dont understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right I had the same problem, in my case it was because I didn't set the fb[YOUR_APP_ID] in the .plist, did u set it correctly?

> Create a new row named URL types with a single item, URL Schemes,
>   containing a single value, fb[YOUR_APP_ID] (the literal characters fb
>   followed by your app ID).

Try using YOUR_APP_ID in the Facebook Hackbook example project, 
find it here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/

To test YOUR_APP_ID you need to change the project in two places:
1) In the .plist file
2) In HackbookAppDelegate.m search for the `kAppId` and set it to YOUR_APP_ID,

```
static NSString* kAppId = @"432606956784814";
```

If this would work then we will know that u know how to set the .plist correctly and that YOUR_APP_ID is valid.

Comment: <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb432606956784814</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>. This is the what i have made.

Comment: Made changes as you said. But Hackbook is also not working  properly after placing my appId. After getting logged in hack book is presenting a screen. Which is having only logout button

Comment: Press the logout button and then login, this should launch the safari

Comment: after pressing logo ut it is presenting log in screen but after logging in again it is directing to log out screen. Thank you for spending your valuable time